# How do I identify imports in javascript code?

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, language-design

My current approach is using a RegEx to identify uses of import and require keywords.

I imagine this is a naive way of doing this, and the correct way to do this would be to modify a Javascript interpreter to capture the moment the code wants to import a file.

Comment: What do you need to identify them for? Why is this question tagged [[tag:syntax-highlighting]]?

Comment: I'm looking to identify imports in files to process and highlight a document tree for developers

Comment: What do you mean by "highlight a document tree"?

Comment: A js parser will be able to find all `import` declarations and dynamic `import`s, as well as calls to a function called `require` (detecting aliases will be more difficult). You can resolve static module identifiers, but you won't be able to get the target module for dynamic calls. Yes, better use a proper AST parser instead of a regex, unless you want to do it quick and dirty.

Comment: Ah thank you. This points me in the right direction. I meant to say a 'dependency tree'